# Looking for: List of 30 top-performing value investors in the US (AUM 100USD mn+; 10 years)

Tags: asset-allocation, fundamentals, investing, value-investing

we are currently looking to build another database sourced by crawling the SEC (freely available at SimFin).

Our goal is to build a monthly updating database showing the holdings of the top value-based investors in the US.

For this we are looking for 2 things:
1. A list of the the top-30 value investors ranked by annualized returns over the last 10 years and the exact fundnames
2. Potential other websites, that already provide this service (as there is no need to recreate the website, if its already out there).

The goal is to allow retail investors analyse the portfolios of top institutional investors and then pick-and-chose their own investment based on this filter.

Thanks a lot for your help!
Max

Comment: Some forum where value investing is specifically discussed would probably be a better source of this info than Quant.StackExchange. It is a bit outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: Point taken, but I actually disagree, since we are building a database that other quantitative investors can us to build automatic decision making processes (since without data, there is no quant finance). Also apart from quant finance on stack exchange, there is no other investment related exchange on the platform. If you do have another platform, do let me know.

Comment: I would start by writing down the names of the people and firms mentioned on this page http://www.grahamanddoddsville.net/?page_id=689  then narrow down/expand the list through slow and patient detective work in the "value investing" community. That page would be my starting point for the search.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! As soon as we have started the database, I'll repost here to share the data.